# How to I change the alignment of the image and text on my wordpress site?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a wordpress site [dishingup.com](http://dishingup.com) and am having issues with the alignment on tablet and mobile

Here it is on mobile:

[image]

And here it is on tablet

[image]

I have tried adding the following CSS in WordPress Customize

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    figure.alignleft, img.alignleft, figure.alignright, img.alignright {
        float:none;
    }
}
```

But feel I must be missing something. Ideally I just want the text to be below the image on mobile and tablet.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please upload your HTML code structure?

Comment: @Alice Hargreaves I have tested in chrome it is working fine.

Comment: This doesnt' really have anything to do with image processing side of things, please remove that tag...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The custom CSS code you added for desktop mode is affecting the elements on smaller devices and you need to override it:

Most likely, adding this to your CSS will help:

```
.list-category li {
  display: flex;
}
@media(max-width: 767px) {
  .list-category li {
    flex-direction: column;      
  }
  .list-category li > a {
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .list-category li .custom-content {
    width: auto;
    margin: 20px;
    padding-left: 0;
  }
}
```

If you don't want the images centered, remove the `margin:0 auto` rule.